# How to setup directx sdk in visual basic 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reference, directx, basic

I am using visual basic 2012. I checked many tutorials on the net. i did exactly as were in tutorials, to add reference to directx in visual basic. but when i run my program it some times shows errors, some times it hangs, some times it doesnt shows any thing and compiles. 
I think in the tutorials they are using different version of visual basic, but how should i add reference to directx in visual basic, so that it runs fine? the given code should work fine because it is exact as in tutorial. i am using visual basic 2012.

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX

Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D

Imports Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput


Public Class Form1

    Dim runonce As Boolean = True
    Dim gamerun As Boolean = True
    Dim bkgcolor As Color = Color.Black
    Dim d3dev As Direct3D.Device
    Dim d3dpp As New PresentParameters ' = New PresentParameters
    Dim drawfont As Direct3D.Font
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim wait As Int32

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        gamerun = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape) Then
            gamerun = False
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim pos As Point
        pos.X = 0
        pos.Y = 0
        Me.Location = pos
        Me.Height = 600
        Me.Width = 800
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        If runonce Then
            Me.Show()
            runonce = False
            init()
            run()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub init()
        d3dpp.DeviceWindow = Me
        d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = Format.X8R8G8B8
        d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = Me.Height
        d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = Me.Width
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard
        d3dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate
        d3dpp.Windowed = True
        d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = True
        d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.D24S8
        d3dev = New Direct3D.Device(0, Direct3D.DeviceType.Hardware, Me, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, d3dpp)
        drawfont = New Direct3D.Font(d3dev, New System.Drawing.Font("IMPACT", 32, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        x = 25
        wait = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub run()
        Do While gamerun
            d3dev.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.Black, 1, 0)
            d3dev.BeginScene()
            drawfont.DrawText(Nothing, "TEST", x, 50, Color.DarkCyan)
            d3dev.EndScene()
            d3dev.Present()
            Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The DirectX SDK's only support for Visual Basic .NET is the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies. These have not been updated in a very long time, and since they are based on .NET 1.1 they won't work with .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5. They only work with .NET 2.0/3.x. VB 2012 uses .NET 4.5.

You should consider looking at an alterative like [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/).

See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx).